# Bootable USB install freezes at "finishing..."

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

I have a problem while installing the bootable USB on Ubuntu. After the installation, it will get to the "finishing..." menu, and be stuck there for a long time. It has been 1 hour now.

I don't know what to do. The bar still moves back and forth. I'm guessing that means it's still working, but 1 hour is a little long for "finishing...".

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the Startup Disk Creator? At the end this program tries to install the bootloader on the USB-stick, and asks for root permission.

Is that what you mean?

I found that when I had the file manager (Nautilus) open, the program failed, or disappeared without installing the bootloader.

(I guess it's because Nautilus is locking the USB stick).

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue, i guess the best option is to simply restart your computer and see if the instalation works. If not, you can re-install it.